# How does Deferred pass values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

Can anyone explain me how the `deffered` part works in this code?.

```
(function() {

 var getPosition = function (options) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();    
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        deferred.resolve,
        deferred.reject,
        options);    
    return deferred.promise();
 };

 var lookupCountry = function (position) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();    
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                        position.coords.latitude,
                        position.coords.longitude);
    var geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geoCoder.geocode({ location: latlng }, deferred.resolve);    
    return deferred.promise();
 };

 var displayResults = function (results, status) {            
    $("body").append("<div>").text(results[0].formatted_address);      
 };

 $(function () {
    $.when(getPosition())
     .pipe(lookupCountry)
     .then(displayResults);
 });    
}());
```

I have a couple of questions on how the above code works..

```
$(function () {
    $.when(getPosition())
     .pipe(lookupCountry)
     .then(displayResults);
});
```

1. How does the above code without passing `options` still work?.
2. What does the `pipe` method do and how is the `position` passed to lookupCountry() method?.
3. What will happen if `deferred.reject` is being triggered in `getPosition` function?

Comment: What you're asking is really why the arguments are passed automatically when a function is referenced, and not called

Comment: @adeneo an interesting thing here is that it seems that the "resolve" and "reject" callbacks are intrinsically bound to each Deferred instance. I didn't know that. Or maybe the innards just don't depend on `this`.

Comment: @Pointy - yes, they are bound to each instance, and you can create as many as you want to. Used to be you would call it as `var def = new $.Deferred()`, but now it does that internally, just like `$()` checks if it's an instanceof itself and returns with the `new` keyword automagically so you don't have to actually write `new` when you call it, it's a pretty nifty way of doing it.

Comment: It's actually off topic but jQuery's `$.Deferred()`, `$.Callbacks()` and `$()` itself all work that way. John Resig was kind enough to explain "new-tollerance" [here](http://www.ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/). Since reading that a few years ago, I have written all my js constructors that way.

Comment: And I can't remember a time when jQuery Deferreds' resolve and reject methods weren't ready bound. I may be wrong but I thought that dated back to v1.5.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I would not be surprised; I've only written code to use $.Deferred a few times so I'm not deeply familiar with the mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function, `getPosition` is called without arguments, but that's fine, because HTML5 geolocation API doesn't need an options object to work.

[navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) expects a success callback (a function) as its first parameter. In this case that function is [deferred.resolve()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.resolve/) which receives and passes whatever arguments it receives to the next step of the chain. Since it receives a valid position, that's what is passes to `lookupCountry`.

`lookupCountry` turns the position into a google.maps.LatLng object, which it feeds to a [google.maps.GeoCoder()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Geocoder) reverse geolocation call, which also expects a success callback function. In this case it passes an array of addresses to the next step of the chain.

`displayResults` will receive an array of address objects, pick the first one and display its formatted address.

The code above does not work magically. Every function receives the expected parameter in the expected position. If the code was modified and `lookupCountry` expected, for example, a comment as the first parameter:

```
var lookupCountry = function (comment, position) {
  ...
}
```

it wouldn't work anymore because it can't just guess what each parameter means.

I'm not sure the above is a good use case for deferreds. The whole code above could be done with

```
$(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var geoCoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geoCoder.geocode({
            location: {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            }
        }, function (results) {
            $("body").append("<div>").text(results[0].formatted_address);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: What will happen if deferred.reject is being triggered in getPosition function and What does the pipe do here? Can it not be another then?

Comment: If geolocation fails then no success callback will be triggered. Ever. But your original function doesn't deal with rejection either. I guess both of them need to display a message like "sorry, we couldn't geolocate your position, your browser doesn't support it or you didn't allow it".  As per using two "then" it is also possible, but they'll have to be nested and you'll need a second when.

Comment: "but they'll have to be nested and you'll need a second when" - pardon!? (a) the question's `.when(...)` is unnecessary, as would be a second one; (b) nesting can be useful but `.then(...).then(...)` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 you are absolutely right. It turns out pipe is even deprecated (Silly me) and since you are returning the promise object, you don't need to use `when` or `done` or whatever. I guess `(getPosition()).then(...)` could work. I wonder what will happen to a chained `then` if the outcome of the first one isn't a promise.

Comment: Hi amenadiel. If the first function returned something other than a promise, `when()` would come into its own with its power to coerce a value to a promise, and thus start a promise chain. `$.when(getPosition())` is a good strategy if `getPosition` was a third party lib method and you didn't know whether it returned a regular value or a promise, or if it unreliably returned a value on some occasions and a promise on others.